# Upgrade Nexus 3.6x.y to latest using docker-compose faild

Tags: docker-compose, nexus3

I am upgrading a docker container for the first time and the nexus repo happens to be the first one. My goal is to upgrade from 3.60.0 to the latest image. I have copied my docker-compose file here.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  nexus:
    # image: sonatype/nexus3:3.60.0
    image: sonatype/nexus3:latest
    container_name: nexus
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/data/nexus/:/nexus-data"
      - nexus-vol:/opt/sonatype
volumes:
    nexus-vol:
```

Now, the nexus container is already running with the 3.60.0 version. After changing the docker image to the latest as above. I executed the two commands below.

```
$ docker-compose pull nexus
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Though, the docker-compose shows it is using the latest image but the webpage is still showing the 3.60.0

```
$ docker-compose images nexus
CONTAINER REPOSITORY TAG IMAGE ID SIZE
nexus sonatype/nexus3 latest bda195cc2883 572MB

$ docker inspect nexus | grep Image
“Image”: “sha256:bda195cc2883a7a3297be87771e3bd09e8e1a0e1b8f113dae864cb013072eac2”,
“Image”: “sonatype/nexus3:latest”

$ curl --include --silent http://localhost:8081/ | grep Server
Server: Nexus/3.60.0-02 (OSS)
```

I am using the persistent volumes. I assume the data in the persistent volumes have to be updated/upgraded, which I don’t know how to do. I don't find any documentation for docker particularly.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I had to avoid using persistent volume for the whole /opt/sonatype instead of that, I should only map volumes for /opt/sonatype/etc/jetty and /opt/sonatype/etc/ssl. So, the jar files directories are overwritten by the new image and the new Nexus OSS version is appeared in the website.